# Draw a rectangle in a PDF document using iText

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Is there a way in iText to draw a rectangle in a PDF document?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the solution.  Thanks Dylan McClung.

```
PdfWriter writer = ...;
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
cb.saveState();
cb.setColorStroke(Color.black);
cb.rectangle(x,y,x1,y1);
cb.stroke();
cb.restoreState();
```

Comment: `PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();`

Comment: cb.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);

Answer (score 3):

In the .NET version I just create a table with a border.  I know it isn't Java but maybe the following code will help you.

```
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, 20, 20, 20, 20);
PdfPTable table;
PdfPCell cell;

// single element w/ border
table = new PdfPTable(1);
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("BOLD WORDS", FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 11, Font.BOLD)));
cell.BorderWidth = 2;
cell.Padding = 5;
cell.PaddingTop = 3;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(cell);
table.SetWidthPercentage(new float[1] { 598f }, PageSize.LETTER);
table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
document.Add(table);
```

Comment: the idea just drawing a table cell is not that bad

Answer (score 3):

A more complete example is at: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/88/iTextSharp-Drawing-shapes-and-Graphics

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void drawRectangle(PdfContentByte content, float width, float height) {
    content.saveState();
    PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
    state.setFillOpacity(0.6f);
    content.setGState(state);
    content.setRGBColorFill(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    content.setLineWidth(3);
    content.rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    content.fillStroke();
    content.restoreState();
}
```

From API of itext

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void rect(PdfWriter writer) {

   PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
   try {
       cb.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, false), 24);
       cb.rectangle(140f,140f,280f,420f);
       cb.stroke();
   } catch (DocumentException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```