# Drawing on PDF file C#

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I need to write a PDF file from my WPF app.
I've seen some 3rd party libraries to create PDF files, but I couldn't find any that would allow me to write boxes, or any shape for the matter.
Do I have to use some 2D library from .NET or is there any PDF library that provides that type of work?

This is what I need to draw:

I'll have a list of objects `List<ObjX> list;` that I'll use to fill each box.
Think of it as a Personal Data list of all employees, for instance.

```
____________________________________
{header_img}

| Name: {name} | Surname: {surname}|

| Address : {address} | City: {cit}|
____________________________________
```

It's a very poor drawing, what I'll do is a bit more elaborated, including even images.

Comment: What libs did you review? Did you look at ITextSharp?

Comment: @acc_at_infosis, did you really? I doubt you'd have posted if you had.

Comment: @antisanity if you don't want to help go do something else... I don't need to prove myself and you don't need to answer.

Comment: @acc_at_infosis, and yet you marked the iTextSharp solution as the answer.

Comment: @antisanity yeah, ok man... thx for ur glorious insight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

You can find lots of help on how to use it by searching StackOverflow. :)

This is an answer to drawing a rectangle: [Draw a rectangle in an iText pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311732/draw-a-rectangle-in-an-itext-pdf)

**Edit**

Also, a search on "drawing shapes iTextSharp" gave me this link which looks quite detailed.  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/88/iTextSharp-Drawing-shapes-and-Graphics

You will need to watch out for differences in version, since 1.4 and 1.5 are quite different.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for your time. I've done some research on iTextSharp but I couldn't find ways to do this drawing I need. That's one problem since I do need these "boxes" for printing purposes.

Comment: Did you look at the link?  It tells you how to draw the boxes.

Comment: Thanks again. I've seen some work like that. But that's exactly the point. Do I have to draw every single line I need everytime? Is there any way to do a template (once) and the just replicate?

Comment: Sure, create a function that does what you need and reuse it.

Comment: just fyi... that last link you provided gave me the answer I needed. I can use tables... haven't seen that. Thanks! 
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take the approach that I did which is to generate your document entirely in WPF and then simply convert it to a bitmap image (very easy in WPF) and then add that bitmap image to a PDF document using iTextSharp. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232676/print-wpf-window-to-pdf-file/8235301#8235301) for more details.

The main advantage to this approach is that you get a PDF that looks exactly like your WPF output. Plus, it takes very little code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution is to use PdfSharp and Migradoc, http://www.pdfsharp.net/ It's free and allow you to do everything.