# How can I draw a rectangle into pdf file and fill it with text?

Tags: java, android, pdf, drawing, pdf-generation

I've started to work on a simple Android project recently, where I have to collect some data from a database and put them into a pdf file.

I'd like to put these data into some rectangles, to get something like this:

[image]

I've read about rectangles on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311732/draw-a-rectangle-in-an-itext-pdf), and I think it's gonna work in Android too.
The only thing I can't get is how to fill my data into the rectangle.

Could you give me any suggestion, please?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar code where i used table and set the value.It may provide you with some hint:

```
private static Font blackFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, Font.BOLD);

private void createSeg_Table(Document document)throws DocumentException,IOException{
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);

        try{

          PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("text you want to show",blackFont));
          c1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
          c1.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
                  table.addCell(c1);                                     
                  document.add(table);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```