# C# create pdf using iTextSharp or PDFsharp

Tags: c#, drawing, pdf-generation, itext

[image: Your image]

I need to create a pdf file in C#. The file should contain a round rectangle with text. I have an object with text value. I need to write this text to a rectangular text field. I try using iTextSharp and PDFsharp libraries, but I can't draw a rectangle as in the picture. Can anyone help me?

Comment: These links might help you: [Drawing on PDF file C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388927/drawing-on-pdf-file-c-sharp) and [Draw a rectangle in iText PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311732/draw-a-rectangle-in-an-itext-pdf). The second link is for Java, but has an answer for C# as well.

Comment: OP, this link might help. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/88/iTextSharp-Drawing-shapes-and-Graphics

Comment: pleace check the link of your image!